# Prepare Pandas DataFrame for excel write

Tags: python, pandas

I have started editing a read.excel, as result see below table:

```
| descr         | serial    | ref                               | type      | val   | qty   | uom   |
|-----------    |--------   |---------------------------------- |--------   |-----  |-----  |-----  |
| Product 1     | NaN       | 12345                             | type 1    | NaN   | 6     | PCS   |
| Product 2     | NaN       | 23456                             | NaN       | NaN   | 4     | PCS   |
| Product 3     | NaN       | 66778 MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1 ...   | type 2    | NaN   | 4     | PCS   |
| Product 4     | NaN       | 88776 MAKER: MANUFACTURER 2 ...   | NaN       | NaN   | 2     | PCS   |
| Product 5     | 500283    | 99117 MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1 ...   | NaN       | NaN   | 12    | PCS   |
| Product 6     | 500283    | 00116 MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1 ...   | NaN       | NaN   | 12    | PCS   |
| Product 7     | 900078    | 307128 MAKER: MANUFACTURER 3 ...  | NaN       | NaN   | 12    | PCS   |
| Product 8     | 900078    | 411354 MAKER: MANUFACTURER 3 ...  | NaN       | NaN   | 2     | PCS   |
```

I am now stuck with 2 problems.

1. If column["ref"] contains string aside int, I need to separate them, put the string in a new column (ref2). 
   I have had my luck with: .split(' ', 1)[0] and  .split(' ', 1)[1].

Q: How do loop over rows, find out if a certain column contains a string besides an int (standard) and split them in two different columns.

2. My output is supposed to be:

```
| ref(int)  | descr                     | qty   |
|---------- |-----------------------    |-----  |
| 12345     | Product 1                 | 6     |
|           | type 1                    |       |
| 23456     | Product 2                 | 4     |
| 66778     | Product 3                 | 4     |
|           | MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1     |       |
|           | type 2                    |       |
| 88776     | Product 4                 | 2     |
|           | MAKER: MANUFACTURER 2     |       |
| 99117     | Product 5                 | 12    |
|           | S/N: 500283               |       |
|           | MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1     |       |
| 00116     | Product 6                 | 12    |
|           | S/N: 500283               |       |
|           | MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1     |       |
| 307128    | Product 7                 | 12    |
|           | S/N: 900078               |       |
|           | MAKER: MANUFACTURER 3     |       |
```

I simply do not know how I can achieve an output like above within a Pandas' DataFrame.

Q2: Assuming I manage to split a cell into two if conditions are met, how do I arrange them according to above example output? (int of column_old went to ref(int)* and Maker: XXX went to column_ref2 and gets composed in column B for output in Excel. Same with type (and possible other columns).

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Please post your example data as text instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

Example csv for me to load in:

```
descr,serial,ref,type,val,qty,uom
Product 1,,12345,type 1,,6,PCS
Product 2,,23456,,,4,PCS
Product 3,,66778 MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1,type 2,,4,PCS
Product 4,,88776 MAKER: MANUFACTURER 2,,,2,
```

Loading in the data and creating a new dataframe called `cleaned` that will be manipulated and massaged for the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw = pd.read_csv("data.csv") # reading in the example file
cleaned = pd.DataFrame() # creating new dataframe 
cleaned['ref (int)'] =  raw['ref'].str.split(' ').str[0].copy() # creating ref (int) column that is just the first plat of the ref colum

# moving the rest of the data over
cleaned['description'] = raw['descr'] 
cleaned['ref_maker'] = raw['ref'].str.split(' ').str[1:].apply(' '.join) # making a new column for the rest of ref description if there is a text part after the integer in the ref column
cleaned['type_full'] = raw['type']
cleaned['qty'] = raw['qty']
```

Now we have a dataframe (`cleaned`) that looks like this:

```
    ref (int) description              ref_maker type_full  qty
0     12345   Product 1                           type 1    6
1     23456   Product 2                              NaN    4
2     66778   Product 3  MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1    type 2    4
3     88776   Product 4  MAKER: MANUFACTURER 2       NaN    2
```

Now we need to clean it

```
cleaned.replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True) # replacing empty strings with NaN
cleaned.set_index(['ref (int)', 'qty'], inplace=True) # fixing ref and qty columns for when it stacks (stacking will help make the multi-lined duplicates you wanted)
cleaned = cleaned.stack().to_frame().reset_index() # stacking the dataframe and then converting it back to a dataframe
```

(for your reference), the `.stack()` command will give you this (which is almost what you want):

```
ref (int)  qty             
12345      6    description                Product 1
                type_full                     type 1
23456      4    description                Product 2
66778      4    description                Product 3
                ref_maker      MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1
                type_full                     type 2
88776      2    description                Product 4
                ref_maker      MAKER: MANUFACTURER 2
```

Now we do a little more cleaning:

```
del cleaned['level_2'] # cleaning up old remnants from the stack (level_2 corresponds to the column names that you dont want in your final output)
cleaned.dropna() # deleting rows that have no values
cleaned.columns = ['ref', 'qty', 'desc'] # renaming the columns for clarity
```

Now it looks like this:

```
    ref (int)  qty                   desc
0     12345    6              Product 1
1     12345    6                 type 1
2     23456    4              Product 2
3     66778    4              Product 3
4     66778    4  MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1
5     66778    4                 type 2
6     88776    2              Product 4
7     88776    2  MAKER: MANUFACTURER 2
```

The last step is to replace the duplicate values with empty strings to make it match your desired output.

```
clear_mask = cleaned.duplicated(['ref', 'qty'], keep='first') # looking for rows where the ref and qty values are the same as above, we dont want that to show up so this creates a series of booleans
cleaned.loc[clear_mask, 'qty'] = '' # setting duplicates to empty strings
cleaned.loc[clear_mask, 'ref'] = ''
cols = cleaned.columns.tolist() # rearranging columns so that qty is at the end
cols.append(cols.pop(cols.index('qty')))
cleaned = cleaned[cols]
print(cleaned)
```

Here is the final output:

```
 ref (int)                   desc qty
0     12345              Product 1   6
1                           type 1    
2     23456              Product 2   4
3     66778              Product 3   4
4            MAKER: MANUFACTURER 1    
5                           type 2    
6     88776              Product 4   2
7            MAKER: MANUFACTURER 2
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! Just one thing: cleaned.set_index(['ref (int)', <- needed to change 'ref' to 'ref (int)' in 2nd segment. Thanks again

Comment: could you tell me how (and where in the code) I could implement the following.

* ref (int) row should stay as it it. I found out how I can change "MAKER:" to "MKR:" for example. I would then like to stitch the other columns together if they stay under 30 chars after all. I would not like to cut columns with concatenation. Thanks anyways.