# Pandas DF arrange cells and add prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe example - result of a previously cleaned pandas.read_excel:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'ref': ['409075', '405168', '035751', '039374', '331949', '331951', '307128'], 
        'description': ['Product 7 (12X)', 'Product 6 (8X)', 'Product 2', 'Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 3'], 
        'maker': [np.nan, np.nan, 'Companyname1', 'Comp.2', 'Company3', 'Company name 4', 'Maker 5'],
        'type': [np.nan, np.nan, 'Rev. 0', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Type 5'],
        'qty': [6, 4, 4, 2, 12, 12, 12],
        'val': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'serial': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 58690, 900078, 69402, 900078]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ref_maker', 'description', 'serial', 'maker', 'type', 'val, ''qty'])
```

Below is the desired output (in columns):

1. ref
2. a) description + b)maker + c) type + d) val + e) serial
3. qty

**condition:** resulting, concatenated description-column must not have more than 30 characters and shouldn't cut imported cells.

(Partially covered in: [Prepare Pandas DataFrame for excel write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245145/prepare-pandas-dataframe-for-excel-write))

```
| ref       | description     (max 30 ch.)  | qty   |
|--------   |----------------------------   |-----  |
| 409075    | Product 7 (12X)               | 6     |
| 405168    | Product 6 (8X)                | 4     |
| 35751     | Product 2                     | 4     |
|           | MKR: Companyname1             |       |
|           | Type: Rev. 0                  |       |
| 39374     | Product 1                     | 2     |
|           | MKR: Comp.2; SRL: 58690       |       |
| 331949    | Product 2                     | 12    |
|           | MKR: Company3; SRL: 900078    |       |
| 331951    | Product 3                     | 12    |
|           | MKR: Company name 4           |       |
|           | SRL: 69402                    |       |
| 307128    | Product 3                     | 12    |
|           | MKR: Maker 5; Type: Type 5    |       |
|           | SRL: 900078                   |       |
```

*I have tried to find solutions, but I did not have success changing them to my needs due to not understanding them (properly). Hope to meet the requirements.*

Thankful for any help and hints.

Comment: Seems like you are just trying to combine 4 columns in your table. You can simple fill missing values with empty string and then use `df.colname1 + df.colname2 + ...` to combine the columns, you can also add keywords as need in between as well: `df.colname1 + "MKR: " + df.colname2`.

Comment: In this way the prefixes for cells with missing values get submitted. I need to shorten the description column cell as much as possible. Although, like said, it can not have more than 30 characters and should not cut the parts.

Comment: You can prefill the columns with the prefix and then append columns that are not empty, this way you won't have extra prefixes with no information.

Comment: I am new to Python and Pandas and unfortunately do not know how I could accomplish prefilling the column (for non-empty ones only?) and appending non-empty columns in multiple rows (not more than 30 characters). Would you please help me, or throw me some keywords to help me find the right way? Thanks @YilunZhang

Comment: I am almost done and would like to answer this question.

Please, can someone tell me how to concatenate multiple columns where their sum is not > 30 characters?

Comment: you can simply concatenate them and then cut off at 30 characters I guess? Unless you want the condition and result to be different.

Comment: @YilunZhang Well, I don't want to cut just after 30 characters, because I might cut through a word or a pair ("XXX: yyyy"). Basically like in the last line of the above output: Product line + columns that get cut after n strings have reached 30 characters. There: 3 strings in 2 additional rows. - thank you - in the worst case I will search on and might issue a new question.